# Why is the Flutter PWA font different than the web font?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, progressive-web-apps, flutter-web

I'm seeing some strange font behavior with my Flutter web deployment vs PWA. Both are using default font (which I believe is Roboto?). On the left is my PWA, on the right is the browser. Both are built using canvaskit. On the second image, I've overlayed the two images together at 50%, so you can see how the font spacing is broken in the PWA.

The strange thing is that I've occasionally see the font render correctly in the PWA, but then after using the app for long enough, it breaks again. I've been unable to reproduce it deterministically.

How can I make both fonts consistent?

[image: pwa vs web]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just use this code in terminal then restart android studio

```
--web-renderer canvaskit
```

Comment: >Both are built using canvaskit